# how to fix fix mapping when input not file xml?

Tags: rest, api, soapui, ibm-datapower

after when me mapping on api manager, log in datapower and bug write source-https (GW_API_DEV01_https_443): Connection terminated before request headers read because of the connection error occurs, from URL 10.xx.xx.xx

cannot get response value with xml request, make it for this required

request

...

response
...

   
      
         
            
               FLEXCUBE
            
         
         
            1
            
               FLEXCUBE
               ST-CIF24
               Customer Unique Identifier Value and Name Combination does not make it unique.This Combination is already being used for the Customer Number 01958984
            
         
         
            
               
                  
                     018
                  
                  I
                  100200
                  RB
                  420000218ESB
                  NGUYEN MANH HUNG
                  
                     CMND
                     1987654378
                     2002-09-09
                     CA Ha Noi
                     2020-09-09
                     VN
                  
                  M
                  1995-12-14
                  G
                  0
                  C
                  MAIL
                  Y
                  VIE
               
            
            
               NGANH NGHE KT-THEO TPB
               KHCN, khong ap dung
            
            
               CHUONG TRINH CIF
               999990
            
            
               QUY MO DOANH NGHIEP
               CHUA KHAI THAC THONG TIN
            
            
               THU NHAP CA NHAN THANG
               CHUA KHAC THAC THONG TIN
            
            
               NHOM_KH_VAY
               KH5
            
            
               NGANH_NGHE_KINH_TE_SBV
               179900
            
            
               420000218ESB

i use api ibm connect

Comment: This is very difficult to understand. Did you use a translator, like google translate?

Answer (score 0):

Any non-xml mappings you should do using GatewayScript!